# powerpoint vba macro not running when shape is clicked

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have created a powerpoint presentation that runs macros with a click of a shape on a slide.  However, I am not able to run the macro from the presentation, only from the editor.

I have searched this site and only found suggestions toward using activepresentation rather than activewindow.  However, I am already using activepresenation as you can see in my below code. Even the msgbox does not come up. Any ideas?

```
Sub start_game()

MsgBox "making things invisible"

Dim i As Integer
Dim slide_count As Integer
Dim shape As shape

i = 1
slide_count = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
MsgBox slide_count

For i = 1 To slide_count

For Each shape In ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes
If shape.Name = "answer_block" Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("answer_block").Visible = False
End If
Next

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you linking the action? I inserted a new shape, selected the shape, Insert -> Links -> Action and selected Run Macro and chose my simple macro.  Worked without having to set anything beyond default.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

hmmmm...that is how i am doing it. The problem maybe that i changed the VBA code.  However, i did try to save the code and powerpoint then closed and reopen with no luck

Comment: I'm assuming your workbook is macro enabled, or at least that part didn't change? Start with a new presentation and see if you can run a simple `msgbox("test")` sub.

Comment: well after completely getting out of powerpoint and reopening the file.  The macros work. 

so questions:
can macros become disabled after enabling them? 

as you can see I am a vba noob